# Why does the bitwise operator OR truncate the value in this example?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

The [Mozilla JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators) has this to say about the bitwise OR operator:

*"Bitwise OR: Returns a zero in each bit position for which the corresponding bits of both operands are zeros."*

However, when operand b is 1, the bitwise operator OR in the example below rounds up `a`. This is something I cannot wrap my head around. Also, seeing as `a` returns a non rounded number, it is also not clear to me how the bitwise operator truncates it down to two digits.

```
var a = Math.random()*100;
console.log(a);
console.log(a | 1);
```

Insightful explanations are very welcome.

Comment: From the page you linked: "The operands are converted to thirty-two-bit integers and expressed by a series of bits (zeros and ones)." The rounding is part of the conversion process.

Comment: @RaymondChen.: Din't read it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hidden factor here is bitwise operators cast the number to an integer before being applied. That is why the number gets rounded. The cast truncates any fractional part.

The bitwise OR itself then simply sets the first bit to 1. So may or may not increase the truncated number by 1 depending on whether it was odd or even after the truncation.

So it's not rounding it up in all cases - just 50% of the time.

Comment: Makes much more sense now, thanks! Is there by any chance a resource you'd recommend detailing this process in more depth?

Comment: @gnzg For the full details, see the JavaScript language specification. There is a link to it from the duplicate.